# Change (toggle) property on passed object

Tags: swiftui

I'm clearly not understanding this in SwiftUI.
I have a task struct with several properties one of which  - 'isHotList' is a Boolean that I want to be able to toggle on and off.

I created a row view for each task and then use this to populate a list view for all the tasks loaded from JSON - no problems there. Moved on and added a detail view (which takes a task object passed in from the list view) with a toggle button for the isHotList the problem is that the toggle works correctly in the detail view but doesn't carry back to the list view .... ?
I suspect I've created two seperate instances of the task but I'm not sure. I've used @State to declare the task but I can't get @Binding to work correctly for me.
Toggle in the detail view, task is declared with @State in this view file ...

```
                   Button(action: {
                    task.isHotList.toggle()
                    print(task.isHotList)
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(task.isHotList ? Color.orange : Color.gray)
                }
```

The list view (separate file)

```
            ForEach(filteredHotTasks) { task in
            NavigationLink(destination: TaskDetail(task: task)) {
                TaskRow(task: task)
            }
        }
```

I'm really trying to learn here but this has me confused as to what is / isn't going on

As requested the full detail view file

```
struct TaskDetail: View {
@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
@State var task: Task

var taskIndex: Int {
    modelData.tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == task.id})!
}

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            HStack {
                Text(task.title)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    task.isHotList.toggle()
                    print(task.isHotList)
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(task.isHotList ? Color.orange : Color.gray)
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text(task.category)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
                    Text(task.dueDate)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share more code.. the whole view with variables would help. Declaring a State in the detail View will not pass the data back.

Comment: That was what I understood however I cant see how to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `@State`

```
struct TaskDetail: View { 
     @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
     var task: Task  /* NEW */

     var taskIndex: Int {
         modelData.tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == task.id})!
    }
}
```

And use

```
Button(action: {
     /* filteredHotTasks is the array that contains tasks. */
     modelData.filteredHotTasks[taskIndex].isHotList.toggle()
     print(task.isHotList)
 })
```

Remember to pass `modelData` using  `.environmentObject(modelData)` somwhere in one of your root views.

If you do not do, use  `@ObservedObject` instead of `@EnvironmentObject`.

```
struct TaskDetail: View { 
     @ObservedObject var modelData: ModelData /* NEW */
     var task: Task  /* NEW */

     var taskIndex: Int {
         modelData.tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == task.id})!
    }
}
```

And

```
NavigationLink(destination: TaskDetail(modelData: modelData, task: task)) {
  TaskRow(task: task)
}
```

---

Have a look at my answer to this question

[Declaring TextField and Toggle in a SwiftUI dynamic form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68145706/declaring-textfield-and-toggle-in-a-swiftui-dynamic-form/68146048#68146048)

For more info, read this article.

[Managing Model Data in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

---

Confirm `Task` to `Equatable` in addition to the rest of the protocols you confirm to.

```
struct Task: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {

}
```

Doing so you avoid using `task.id` whenever you want to know if two tasks are equal as in the `firstIndex`

```
var taskIndex: Int {
    modelData.tasks.firstIndex(where: {$0 == task})!
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the great explanation :)